# BizTalk 2020 with MQSC adapter

Tags: ibm-mq, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I'm migrating a BizTalk 2013 R2 env to BizTalk 2020 and facing an issue with the adapter MQSC. The flow uses the IBM client installed with Host Integration 2020. We notice the add of 2 new properties on the adapter

[image: MQSC properties]

We left these properties with the default values, but when sending a message with a one way MQSC send port it remains active and the following error is logged twice in the event log:
[image: The Messaging Engine encountered an error while deleting one or more messages.]

> The Messaging Engine encountered an error while deleting one or more messages.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: What errors are logged in the queue manager?  On the client you should also have an AMQERR01.LOG,  what errors are logged here?

Comment: this doesn't seem to be related to programming, right?

Comment: @JoshMc no log added to AMQERR01.LOG when the error is raised. I'm checking with MQ team if there is any log from queue manager side.

Comment: @Vega  BizTalk is a bit of an edge case, it is a mixture of server configuration and programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing only the "IBM MQ Client Type" property to "IBM MQ .Net Client"